# creating array without declaring the size - java

Tags: java, arrays, size, declare

i've digging around about the same issue but i couldn't find the same as i had

i want to create an array without declaring the size because i don't know how it will be !

to clear the issue i'd like to give you the code that i'm looking up for

```
public class t
{
 private int x[];
 private int counter=0;
 public void add(int num)
 {
   this.x[this.counter] = num;
   this.counter++;
 }
}
```

as you see the user could use the `add` function to add element to the array 10000 times or only once so it's unknown size

Comment: [`java.util.ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Yea, use ArrayList; it's like an array that can grow dynamically, you can get by index, put by index, put at end.... it's convenient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Java.util.ArrayList or LinkedList is the usual way of doing this. With arrays that's not possible as I know.

Example:

```
List<Float> unindexedVectors = new ArrayList<Float>();

unindexedVectors.add(2.22f);

unindexedVectors.get(2);
```

Answer (score 10):

You might be looking for a `List`? Either `LinkedList` or `ArrayList` are good classes to take a look at. You can then call `toArray()` to get the list as an array.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, use `ArrayList`. Here's how:

```
public class t
{
 private List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 public void add(int num)
 {
   this.x.add(num);
 }
}
```

As you can see, your `add` method just calls the `ArrayList`'s add method. This is only useful if your variable is private (which it is).

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping the ArrayList in another class?

Comment: If this is the entire class, then there is no purpose. But I wanted to show the OP how to use `ArrayList`s with his own code.

Answer (score 3):

Once the array size is fixed while running the program ,it's size can't be changed further.
So better go for ArrayList while dealing with dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
    private Object element[] = new Object[] {};
```

Comment: this basically says an array of size 0 . I doubt this would work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).  Arrays in Java are not like those in Javascript.