# How to make a Java array behave like a JavaScript array?

Tags: java

In JavaScript, I can write code like this:

```
var a = new Array();
a[2] = 'a';
a[20] = 'b';
```

and this would not work on Java, the point is I don't want to specific the exact length for it.

How could I keep this happy style when writing java?

Comment: I might be wrong, but the way you're using the array seems to suggest that you actually want a map -- i.e., it seems as though you want to get `'a'` when you put in `2`, to get `'b'` when you put in `20`.

Comment: In JavaScript, you have an Array - and it does a lot of things. In Java, you can (and should) choose between plain arrays, Set, List, and Map, to name just a few of the main collections. There are specialized containers for particular operations. All this choice allows you to write faster, more efficient applications than would be possible with JavaScripts' "one-size-fits-all" approach.

Comment: are you still interested in an answer? or do you want to give us more precisely informations?

Comment: thank you all, It just kind of wild to me since I spent lot of time on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specific length you can use List like this:

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add('a');
list.add('b');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Java is to Javascript as ham is to hamster. There is no reason to believe they have the same syntax.

If you want a sparse array, use a `Map`:

```
final Map<Integer, Character> a = new LinkedHashMap<>();
a.put(2, 'a');
a.put(20, 'b');
```

Comment: I don't think a Map is the better structure to use as an array. It has other purposes...

Comment: @Dani sorry what? A `Map` is an excellent sparse array as _is_ used for that purpose. After all, what is an array apart from a special case of a `Map`?

Comment: It's only an opinion. Of course you can use a Map as an array, buy I think Map is a data structure to store values related with some key, and key normally has another meaning that just a position on the list. It's something subjetive, sorry

Comment: @Dani then it's a wrong opinion. I don't understand where you are coming from. Why would using an array with `50` empty spaces to store two values be better than using a `Map` specifically designed for the task?

Comment: Normally, if you are using an array you are going to use all the positions of it, it can grow and decrease, but you are not going to leave empty positions. If you are going to leave a lot of empty position of course, map is better, but in this case it's weird to first think in an array, the key of the map probably has another meaning beyond a simple index. If you are using and array is because the index is important only to put an element on the left or in the right of another, just an ordering issue. If the key has another meaning probably the keys are not going to have consecutive value

Comment: Ok, I understand your position. It is only a meaning issue. I think it is like if you use a car to sleep, yes, you can sleep on the car, but it's designed for travel. It's only a subjetive opinion. Sorry.

Comment: @Dani it's not like that at all. A `Map` is _specifically_ designed for use as a sparse array. I don't understand your position at all.

Comment: Ok, I only say that if you initially thought to use an array is because it's not going to be sparse. If not, you probably first think it another structure like a map, yes. But I don't think of a map as an sparse array, only like a set of key-value where the key doesn't have an ordering meaning. If the array is sparse, probably the indexes don't indicate an order, and your first thought was to use another collection and not an array

Comment: Note that LinkedHashMap does not guarantee that 1 comes before 2 -- this will only happen if 1 is actually inserted *before* 2.

Answer (score 0):

`Java` and `JavaScript` are two deferent languages. you can't do same thing in both

In `Java` you can write

```
char[] arr=new char[2];
arr[0]='a';
arr[1]='b';
```

**If you don't want to specific the length, you can use `List` in `Java`**

```
List<Character> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add('a');
list.add('b');
```

Comment: could I get rid of defining a length for it?

Comment: @igonejack you can use `List` in `Java`

Comment: `"You have to..."` ammm...it may be `"you can..."`, he can implement other collections also..!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you want an array of characters you can do it like this:

```
char[] array = new char[30];
array[2] = 'a';
array[20] = 'b';
```

Comment: thank you, what can I do when I don't want to specific the length?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you are going to use an array of a fixed size you can use:

```
char myarray[]=new char[50];
myarray[2]='a';
myarray[20]='b';
```

If you are going to change the size of the array  dynamically you can use a Collection like an ArrayList (look at the doc) and insert chars in the positions you want

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out: Java and JavaScript are two different things. For containers with variable size there is the [Java collections framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

But wich to choose? That depends on what you need. From your question I can imagine two cases:

#### a variable sized, indexed container:

basically an array-like list. In Java there's besides other list implementations the `ArrayList` used as follows:

```
List<Character> myList = new ArrayList<Character>(); 

// insert element at the end of the list
myList.add('a');

// insert element at specific position in list
myList.add(1, 'b');

// this will fail, because there's no element at position 2!!!
myList.add(3, 'c')
```

#### a container for mappings from integer to character:

In java there's lots of map implementations, I propose the `HashMap`, used like this:

```
Map<Integer,Character> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,Character>(); 

// insert mappings int -> char
myMap.put(0, 'a');
myMap.put(1, 'b');
myMap.put(20, 'c');
```

Each Container serves a different purpose. I advise reading the [Java collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) to be able to choose the best fitting one. Also take a look at tucuxi's answer, as he presented a solution wich simulates the desired beahviour but consider that (as he said himself) **this is not the java way of doing things!**

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own. You will not get the syntax, but most of the flavor will still be there.

*Note that, efficiency-wise, this is a terrible idea*. You can write *much* better code by learning "the Java way" of doing things. This is true of all languages: programming against the grain of the language is sure to cause you pain.

But here is the code:

```
class MyArray<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public MyArray<T>() { super(); }
    public void add(int i, T value) { 
        if (size() < i) { 
            ensureCapacity(i+1); // grow at most once instead of multiple times 
            while (size() < i)) { 
                add(null); // extend with a null object
            }
            add(value);
        } else {
            add(i, value);
        }
    }            
}
```

Now you can compare a garden-variety `ArrayList` with an instance of `MyArray`:

```
ArrayList<Character> a = new ArrayList<>();
MyArray<Character> b = new MyArray<>()
a.add(10, 'X'); // IndexOutOfBoundsException, size is 0
b.add(10, 'X'); // no exception - you get [10 x null, 'X']
b.get(10);      // returns 'X'
```

Bear in mind that JavaScript arrays can be indexed by arbitrary objects and not only integers -- but that the JavaScript VM tries to use numerically-indexed arrays if at all possible. For arbitrary indexing, you would need to use a Java `HashMap`:

```
class MyArray2<T> extends HashMap<Object, T> {
    public MyArray2<T>() { super(); }
    public void add(Object o, T value) { set(o, value); }
}
```

You would then use as:

```
MyArray2<Character> c = new MyArray2<>()
c.add("anything", '?');
c.get("anything"); // returns '?'
```

Comment: this is brutal. in my opinion the op needs a different type of container and not a messed up variant (no offense!) of a non-fitting one. what meaning has size() then in your version? no downvote from me but i don't like the approach...

Comment: It is somewhat tongue in cheek - but it *is* what the OP asked for. Automagically-growing arrays *are* possible in Java, and the above implementation is *why* we mostly avoid them. I am now curious to see how Rhino (JS in Java) implements them...

Comment: Your second example is completely wrong! If you add an `Integer` and a `String` to a `TreeMap` then it will explode - there is no natural ordering of an `Integer` and a `String` unless you define a `Comparator<Object>` and pass it to the `TreeMap` on construction.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - completely true; replaced the `TreeMap` with a `HashMap`

Comment: The issue with a `HashMap` is that it doesn't have _any_ order - looping over values would produce a random order. A `LinkedHashMap` preserves order of insertion, which is probably sufficient.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no order guarantee in JS maps either; also, a `LinkedHashMap` does not guarantee that 1 comes after 2, unless 1 is actuall inserted after 2...

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
char arr[]=new char[30]; //declares an array which can hold 30 characters
    arr[2]='a';
    arr[20]='b';
```

but if you don't want to specify the length,than arraylist is something which will help you to accomplish your task because array's size is always fixed in Java

Comment: oh, thank you, but I mean I don't want to specific the length when defining an array.

Comment: You can't... an array's size is always fixed in Java. Typically instead of using an array, you'd use an implementation of List<T> here - usually ArrayList<T>, but with plenty of other alternatives available.

You can create an array from the list as a final step, of course - or just change the signature of the method to return a List<T> to start with.

Comment: see this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990514/creating-array-without-declaring-the-size-java